# StateObject set to an object with an init() that throws

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to set `@StateObject` to an object that has an `init()` that `throws`? When I try I get the error:

`Call can throw, but it is executed in a non-throwing autoclosure`

I tried creating a `@StateObject` property and giving it a type without setting it to a value:

`@StateObject var myObject: MyObject`

In the class `init()` I set its value using the underscore method:

`_myObject = StateObject(wrappedValue: MyObject())`

(The `init()` of `MyObject` throws)

Comment: What do you want to do instead, if the initialiser for the state object *actually* throws? How do you plan to handle the error?

Comment: I think the answer is "no, you can't initialize any properties using a throwing initializer," so I suggest re-thinking the overall design.

Comment: Yeah I'd suggest re-thinking how this works. Maybe your StateObject has a method `setMyObject()` that can throw. I found [this new Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject) to be super helpful when I was playing with initialisers for @StateObjects.

Comment: You could also look at initialising myObject in your parent view, so you deal with the error there, before creating the child view. What is the child view meant to display/do if the object throws?

Comment: @Sweeper if the init() throws an Error I will show an Alert and then dismiss the view (which is presented as a .sheet)

Comment: @JacobDyer it seems like if I want to call a throwing init/method I'm going to have to do it in a function and not an init() then